# How to compare two variables in meteor HTML

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to compare Database values to DATATYPE=['Text','Boolean,'Number']

Already tried these two methods

Method 1: https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers

```
{#each variant}}
            <li>
         {{#each VARIENTS}}
               {{this.NAME}}
               {{this.DATATYPE}}

           {{#if $eq {{this.DATATYPE}} "Text"}}
  Show this text
 {{/if}}

           {{/each}}
            </li>
           {{/each}}
```

Not working
Method 2: JS File:

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(var1, var2) {
      return var1 === var2;
    });
Not working
```

Comment: You can register global helpers with ```Template.registerHelper("compare", function(var1, var2) {})```. Which meteor version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to compare array to value you should create some loop in registered helper - obviously you can't match array to string.
And in html it should be like

```
{{#if compare this.DATATYPE 'value'}}
```

I assume you want to use it more than once, if not just create regular helper

## EDIT

Oh if VARIENTS is array then your helper is ok, you just used DATATYPE variable in different contexts

Also your first example should work if you delete mustaches in {{this.DATATYPE}}

Comment: {{#if compare this.DATATYPE 'Text'}}<p>Yes it is text</p>{{/if}}

Answer (score 1):

Processing and logic should never be done in html!
Do it in a helper and return a collection.

```
Template.body.helpers({
    VARIENTS2: function() { 
    var x = Varients.find({}, { sort: { rank: -1}}); };
    var y = [];
    var type;
    switch(this.DATATYPE) {
        case "text": type = "t"; break;
        case "boolean": type = "b"; break;
        case "value": type = "blah"; break;
    }
    y.push(type);
    return y;
});
```

Comment: Logic isn't in HTML, it's helper with arguments